# What is the recommended way to insert current date in an Excel cell, as a constant?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

I have been using the following code:

```
private void InsertDate(string dstCoordinates)
{
    Range dstRange   = worksheet.get_Range(dstCoordinates);
    dstRange.Formula = "=TODAY()";
    dstRange.Locked  = true;
}
```

Which re-evaluates the date every time the spreadsheet file is opened.

But now I need the date to be evaluated once, when it is inserted in the cell. From that moment on, the value should remain constant.

That value seems to be stored internally as double.

Perhaps what I need is a function as follows:

```
string today = ExcelEvaluate("=TODAY()");
dstRange.value2 = today;
```

Is there such facility?

TIA

Comment: Are you looking for `DateTime.Now.Date`? - As in `DateTime value = DateTime.Now.Date;`.

Comment: If that internal number is properly accepted by Excel (which I somehow doubt), then yes: that is what I am looking for.

Comment: The problem is that C# is very strongly typed while Excel is extremely weakly typed.

Comment: I *think* Excel uses `OADate`, so you could try `someExcelCell.Value = DateTime.Now.Date.ToOADate()`. Sorry, I don't have Access (-_-) to Excel right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Corak wrote you can probably use `ToOADate()`. You need to set the cell format to date after it, so that it doesn't display as a double. The `TODAY()` function does that automatically.

Here's the code:

```
dstRange.Value2 = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
dstRange.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```